# Locked webBrowser form

Tags: c#

How do I solve a crash problem with webBrowser?

This code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            _progresso = new Progresso();
            _progresso.ShowDialog();
        }

 private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _progresso.Close();
        _impressaoBoleto.webBrowser.Navigate(_arquivo);
        _impressaoBoleto.ShowDialog();


    }
```

it generates several images and presents it in the webBrowser, however when I have more than 100 images it locks the application and raises the process of the machine.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are eating the systems resources. (You can see that if you start you task manager, go to details, and add the "Handles" column. Then watch it grow as your program runs)

There are two things you can consider:

**The IDisposable Interface**

Always dispose of objects that contain the IDisposable interface.

For example, try to change that code:

```
 _progresso = new Progresso();
 _progresso.ShowDialog();
```

to:

```
using (_progresso = new Progresso())
{
 _progresso.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Instance creation**

Also, the Backgroundworker needs to be disposed properly or instantiated only once.

You are excessively using resources when you let it run that way. Try using one instance instead of creating new instances and registering to their events evertime you click.

You could, for example, remove that lines:

```
// BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
// _progresso = new Progresso();
```

and put it them into your constructor.

Also, when your class is not implementing IDisposable, implement it. Then dispose them as well, by implementing the disposable interface..

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing);
```

If helpful, please accept the answer..

Greetings, Mike

Comment: I made the switch, but it still didn't work, it keeps crashing.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify on disposing components.

Could you also post the whole class. you seem to have a problem with using and properly disposing of the components, and when i see the class, i can answer more exact